# Problem with footnote position

Tags: footnotes

i'm having problems with footnote position.
For example, here in this picture: [image]

The footnote is in the end of page, but sometimes it gets too high, like:

[image]

There's something I can do to fix this? I'm pretty new in Latex

And sorry for my english, I'm still practicing... haha

Comment: Footnotes are placed on the page that they occur. If they were pushed to a subsequent page there would be no corresponding footnote mark and text. That's just how footnotes work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a long-standing problem that footnotes might not be flush to the bottom of the page in the default document classes. Either use another document class, like memoir or one of the koma-script ones, or use a package like footmisc for generalized footnote configuration.